# How are these circuit diagrams in Grover's algorithm understood and why are they designed this way?

Tags: quantum-gate, grovers-algorithm, oracles

[image]

As shown in the figure, there are two labelled quantum states 000, 101. why are 3 $Z$-gates placed first in the phase oracle and then 2 controllable $Z$-gates in sequence?

What is the logic that makes up this? Also, I'm curious as to why the Boolean Oracle doesn't use $X$-gates when 011 and 100 are labelled. Instead, $CNOT$ or $CCX$ gates are used instead?

My digital circuit fundamentals are so poor that I can't grasp these patterns; besides, these diagrams are from [(C. Figgatt et al., 2017)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-017-01904-7#Sec1).

This article lists many cases where I tried to discover patterns in the placement of these Oracle's quantum gates, but I failed.

[image]